# App installing take a long time after uninstall in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

One time i Delete flutter app, After that i was trying to Reinstall , but that take very long time. I was waited of lots of time, But nothing changed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **file** -> **Open** -> **Select a android** -> **open in new
   window** -> **connect your device** and **Run** android project.
2. After that you try to **Run** your Flutter project.
3. open this image for result
   [image: Finally I solved the problem]